# Limit the number of sentences in a string

Tags: python

A beginner's Python question:

I have a string with x number of sentences. How to I extract first 2 sentences (may end with . or ? or !)

Comment: Consider "Mr. Rogers went to the store." : Is that 2 sentences?

Comment: Filter your list of sentences to remove the ones that end in single letters or with specific abbreviations, like "Mr", "Mrs", "Ms", "Ltd", "etc", etc.  Consult a list or make your own.  Some are indeterminate - for example, is "Mass." necessarily a state abbreviation?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve that is leading you to this? Natural language parsing is not for the faint of heart, so if you can define your situation better you may get more useful answers.

Comment: Indeed it is not and actually I abandoned that particular project.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ignoring considerations such as when a `.` constitutes the end of sentence:

```
import re
' '.join(re.split(r'(?<=[.?!])\s+', phrase, 2)[:-1])
```

EDIT: Another approach that just occurred to me is this:

```
re.match(r'(.*?[.?!](?:\s+.*?[.?!]){0,1})', phrase).group(1)
```

Notes:

1. Whereas the first solution lets you replace the 2 with some other number to choose a different number of sentences, in the second solution, you change the 1 in `{0,1}` to one less than the number of sentences you want to extract.
2. The second solution isn't quite as robust in handling, e.g., empty strings, or strings with no punctuation. It could be made so, but the regex would be even more complex than it is already, and I would favour the slightly less efficient first solution over an unreadable mess.

Comment: Thanks, that worked, altho it returned a list. I tried to get it back into a string using a for loop and inserting .'s manually. Except there are no ? or ! sentences in my strings anymore :)

Comment: if `sentences` is the list that gets returned then just do `". ".join(sentences)` to get it as a string

Comment: @aaronasterling: I've amended my answer to retain the punctuation and rejoin the sentences.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it like this: [Separating sentences](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/200804/separating_sentences.html), though a comment on that post also points to [NLTK](http://www.nltk.org/code), though I don't know how to find the sentence segmenter on their site...

Answer (score 0):

Here's how yo could do it:

```
str = "Sentence one? Sentence two. Sentence three? Sentence four. Sentence five."
sentences = str.split(".")
allSentences = []
for sentence in sentences
    allSentences.extend(sentence.split("?"))

print allSentences[0:3]
```

There are probably better ways, I look forward to seeing them.

Comment: Ah, Marcelo's solution is indeed much better. Didn't know there was a regex split function.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a step by step explanation of how to disassemble, choose the first two sentences, and reassemble it.  As noted by others, this does not take into account that not all dot/question/exclamation characters are really sentence separators.

```
import re

testline = "Sentence 1.  Sentence 2?  Sentence 3!  Sentence 4.  Sentence 5."

# split the first two sentences by the dot/question/exclamation.
sentences = re.split('([.?!])', testline, 2)
print "result of split: ", sentences

# toss everything else (the last item in the list)
firstTwo = sentences[:-1]
print firstTwo

# put the first two sentences back together
finalLine = ''.join(firstTwo)
print finalLine
```

Answer (score 0):

Generator alternative using my utility function returning piece of string until any item in search sequence:

```
from itertools import islice
testline = "Sentence 1.  Sentence 2?  Sentence 3!  Sentence 4.  Sentence 5."
def multis(search_sequence,text,start=0):
    """ multisearch by given search sequence values from text, starting from position start
        yielding tuples of text before found item and found sequence item"""
    x=''
    for ch in text[start:]:
        if ch in search_sequence:
            if x: yield (x,ch)
            else: yield ch
            x=''
        else:
            x+=ch
    else:
        if x: yield x

# split the first two sentences by the dot/question/exclamation.
two_sentences = list(islice(multis('.?!',testline),2)) ## must save the result of generation
print "result of split: ", two_sentences

print '\n'.join(sentence.strip()+sep for sentence,sep in two_sentences)
```